# Is it posible to make phone call with OpenURLAction in SwiftUI 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, openurl

I am trying to use [**OpenURLAction**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction#declaration) to open the phone app and call the taped number.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
let phoneUrl = URL(string:"tel://1234567890")!

var body: some View {
    Button("1234567890") {
        openURL(phoneUrl)
      }
  }
}
```

This code builds but when I tap nothing happens and I get this error message: **Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)"**

Everything I find on the internet either uses NSURL or a different method, so I wonder how to get it to work? If someone could test this on a real device I would be thankful!

Comment: Did you test on real device? Phone feature is not available in Simulator/Preview.

Comment: I have not. Out of all the answers I found on the internet I did not read that it does not work in Simulator/Preview. I do not have a device to test it on right now, so I guess it works. @Asperi

Comment: I tried your code on my iPhone, it works, no Error